# jQuery Masonry - can't get to work - missing something obvious?

Tags: jquery-masonry

I've already made my page, and tried adding Masonry to it and failed. After racking my brain with several variations and using examples found on [their site](http://Masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-multi-column.html) I decided to strip it right down to its core to get it working separately before I put it back into my code. It still doesn't work on its own, and I've added everything I can think and see (on their site) required to make Masonry work.

- I do have javascript enabled in my browser.
- I have checked that both script sources are correct.
- I have both the jQuery and Masonry .js files.
- I've tried a clearfix class, using the same code from their source on the container  `div`.
- I've taken into account the margin which makes my `.box` class elements 420px even though they have the width of 400px.
- They are floating correctly, just Masonry is not working at all for me.

Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GY4mj/1/) for what I mean, and if your monitor isn't wide enough to see the columns floating in the fiddle frame then see [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/GY4mj/show/).

The masonry examples on their site work fine, so it's nothing to do with my browser - just something I'm missing out on something obvious in my code. If someone could just point me out where I'm going wrong that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Same to me, later i notice that we must wrap the script in a `function()` like this:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.box'
        });
    });
});
```

BTW, in masonry official sample (image demo) they still miss this (maybe its obviously easy - but newbie got hit)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will still be useful to you, but you just need to stick the code before the closing body tag, and make sure that you call the jQuery file before Masonry

http://jsfiddle.net/cbmunro/GY4mj/6/